# user defined function not working in php

Tags: php, function, pdo, unique-id

I have a problem in calling my `rand_id()` function. here is  code as

```
<?php 
try

{

$config=array(
'DB_USERNAME'=>'root',
'DB_PASSWORD'=>'');


$conn=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scc',$config['DB_USERNAME'],$config['DB_PASSWORD']); 
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

echo rand_id(); 

}

catch(Exception $e)
{
echo 'error: '.$e->getMessage();
}

function rand_id()
{

$id=rand(100,103);          //i have record with id ='100'
$results=$conn->query("select id from student_personal_info where id='".$id."'");

if($results->rowCount()>0)
{   
rand_id();
}
else
{
return "this is unique id";
}
}
?>
```

but if I remove the function and check this code working fine but now i can't generate unique id message after checking with database...plz help......

Here is another code after removing function

```
<?php 

try
{
$config=array(
'DB_USERNAME'=>'root',
'DB_PASSWORD'=>'');

$conn=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scc',$config['DB_USERNAME'],$config['DB_PASSWORD']); 
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$id=rand(100,103);          //i have record with id ='100'
$results=$conn->query("select id from student_personal_info where id='".$id."'");

if($results->rowCount()>0)
{   
echo  "generate again";
}
else
{
echo  "this is unique id";
}
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo 'error: '.$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem or error?!

Comment: Would you please reformat your code with meaningful indentation?

Comment: try separating your function from the query and make it `return` a value let the check outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database object `$conn` is out of scope in the `rand_id()` function. You could pass it as an argument:

```
function rand_id($conn)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or use the `global` method:

```
function rand_id()
{
    global $conn;
    // $conn is now accessible
}
```

More info about [Variable Scope on the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

---

For future debugging, remember to check your error log. In this case you should have something like:

> Fatal Error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in ...